A random point $X$ from $(0,1)$ is selected. After $X$ is selected, $Y$ is selected from $(0,x^2)$. Find the marginal p.d.f. $f_2(y)$

A random point $X$ from $(0,1)$ is selected. After $X$ is selected, $Y$ is selected from $(0,x^2)$. Find the marginal p.d.f. $f_Y(y)$.

Well, I assume a constant probability throughout the region $R=\{(x,y):,\text{ } 0\lt x\lt 1, \text{ } 0\lt y\lt x^2\}$ so $$c\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{x^2}dydx=1\implies c=3$$
Next,
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx=3\int_0^1dx=3$$ so $f_Y(y)=3$ for $0\lt y\lt x^2$. Is this correct? It doesn't seem like it should be greater than $1$.

You shouldn't be assuming a constant probability throughout the allowable region. You'd expect a higher density around $(0.9,0.1)$ than around $(0.4,0.1)$, because $f_{Y|X}(0.1|0.4)$ is higher than $f_{Y|X}(0.1|0.9)$, assuming $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,x^2)$ and $f_X(0.9)=f_X(0.4)$, again assuming uniform distribution.

It should be clarified if $X$ is chosen uniformly over $(0,1)$, likewise, if $Y$ is then chosen uniformly over $[0,x^2]$. But generally, you want to condition $f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)dx$.

@Michael Yes, chosen uniformly. So to find $f_Y(y)$, how do I get each part of that integral? Especially $f_X(x)$?

@ZoeAllen that would probably make sense. However, I had a homework problem where the approach involved making that assumption. A point was chosen from a disk, and then I integrated $c$ over the $y$-bounds given in terms of $x$ to get $f_X(x)$. Also, what should I do instead?

I can't comment on your other homework problem. You should use Michael's approach, which is always how to address finding the unconditional distribution from the conditional distribution. You know $f_X$ because you know the distribution of $X$- you've said it's chosen uniformly on $(0,1)$. You know $f_{Y|X}$ because you know that for a given value of $x$, $Y$ is chosen uniformly on $(0,x^2)$. You should know what the probability density function of a uniform distribution is.

There is no reason to believe that the joint density of $(X,Y)$ should be uniform on its support.  We have a hierarchical model:
$$X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1), \\
Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,X^2).$$
(I am assuming the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is uniform although it is not explicitly stated in the question.)  We are asked to determine $f_Y(y)$, the marginal/unconditional density of $Y$.
The idea is to recall that
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x),$$
where $f_X(x)$ is the marginal density of $X$ and $f_{Y \mid X}$ is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$.  The former is straightforward, because $X$ is "chosen first":
$$f_X(x) = \mathbb 1 (0 \le x \le 1) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$
where $\mathbb 1$ is the usual indicator function.  The conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ is
$$f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \mathbb 1 (0 \le y \le x^2)$$ because the length of the interval $[0, x^2]$ is $x^2 - 0 = x^2$, and so if a random variable $Y \mid X = x$ is selected uniformly at random from $[0,x^2]$, its density must be normalized by the length of the interval.
Therefore, the joint density is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2} \mathbb 1 (0 \le x \le 1) \mathbb 1 (0 \le y \le x^2) = \frac{1}{x^2} \mathbb 1 (0 \le y \le x^2 \le 1),$$
where we have simplified the indicator function appropriately.
All that remains is to integrate to obtain the marginal density of $Y$, taking care to note that if $0 \le y \le x^2 \le 1$, then we require that $\sqrt{y} \le x \le 1$:
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=\sqrt{y}}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx,$$
for $0 \le y \le 1$.  We are allowed to drop the indicator because we have restricted the interval of integration to the interval on $x$ for which the indicator equals $1$.
The remainder of the calculation is left as an exercise.
